# What are the message formats in `/var/log/syslog` and the output of `dmesg`?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog, dmesg

On Debian or Ubuntu, what are the formats of `/var/log/syslog` and the output of `dmesg`?

In `/var/log/syslog`, I figure from

```
Apr  1 08:15:01 mycomputer CRON[12494]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

that its log message format is

```
timestamp hostname program-name[pid]: unstructured-message
```

In output of `dmesg`, I figure from

```
[    0.309493] system 00:01: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
```

that its message format is

```
[timestamp] ?  ?: [?] unstructured-message
```

But they are just guesses, certainly with missing and wrong parts.

`/var/log/syslog` is written by `rsyslogd`, which might (or not?) follow the syslog protocol for receiving messages, but may write the messages in different format. The manpage of `rsyslogd` doesn't say anything about the message format, if I am correct.

The output of `dmesg` is exactly what the kernel follows when it writes the messages. It is unrelated to the syslog protocol. So there is more unknown. The manpage of `dmesg` doesn't say any thing about the message format, if I am correct.

Comment: Do you not know about Internet Search Engines?

Comment: Do you not know that Linux, `syslogd`, `rsyslogd` are Open Source?

Comment: You can log a message many different ways. See `logger --help`

Comment: I think everything after the hostname is up to the application logging the message, there's no standard format.